# atan2 (y,x) when y & x are very small

Tags: c, atan2

I tried `atan2` in C with argument of about 10<sup>-14</sup>. 
It gives a wrong answer: around 90 instead of zero, e.g.:

```
void main()
{
    double a =3.4e-14;
    double b=9e-10;
    atan2(3.4e14,9.0e-9); // returns ~90 instead of zero or Not a number
}
```

Comment: `atan2(y,x)` where `y` (`3.4e14`) is MUCH larger than `x` (`9.0e-9`) by orders of magnitude is, indeed, ~90 degrees. So it's giving you the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

You've defined two variables `a` and `b` in your code, 
but then you are using *constants* as arguments to `atan2`.

The values of `a` and `b` are just ignored.

```
atan2(a, b);
```

would return a value near zero, as you would expect.

Same for `atan2(3.4e-14,9.0e-9)` (note `e-14`, not `e14`).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling atan2 on 3.4*10^14, not 3.14*10^(-14)?